# Braintree in Sandbox with Javascript SDK tokenizeCard return "Unable to tokenize card."

Tags: javascript, node.js, braintree

I am using Nodejs + javascript SDK, in which I am creating a new customer using predefined customer ID, which is working fine.

Now, using the same customer Id, I am generating a token at the backend and send it to the client. Now at client I am running .

```
    var card = {
    number: '4111111111111111',
    cvv: '832',
    expirationMonth: '10',
    expirationYear: '2020',
    cardholderName: 'Ankur Agarwal',

    billingAddress: {
      postalCode: '560076'
    },
  };

  var client = new braintree.api.Client({clientToken: clientToken});
  client.tokenizeCard(card, function (err, nonce) {


  // Got Error "Unable to tokenize card"

  })
```

Here is the http response it originally got from the server.

```
/**/callback_json1({"error":{"message":"User does not have the required permissions for this action"},"fieldErrors":[],"status":403})
```

I have enabled the API access for the account in the sandbox

Comment: I got this error because of bad clientToken. Tried to use predefined token, but after that created it in php with $clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate(); All js code is absolutely the same. Also, you can get error if some actions have been done to this moment and old token became invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some extra parameters which are not in docs, due to which its givng such a response. Once I removed the extra parameters from the request, its working fine.

Comment: What were the extra parameters?

Comment: @hrehman When I tried it, I copied json object which had some extra keys which should not be part of request, as mentioned in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar error and it was caused by invalid client token. I was passing `MerchantId` instead of `MerchantAccountId` as a parameter.

```
Gateway.ClientToken.generate(new ClientTokenRequest()
{
    MerchantAccountId = "Your MerchantAccountId" // NOT MerchantId
});
```

To manage your merchant accounts login to your Braintree control panel, go to *Settings* -> *Processing* and scroll down to *Merchant Accounts*